# AIX Version 6.1 tar script

Tags: tar, aix

I need to create a script in AIX Version 6.1 that create a zip file containing a txt and several pdf. I am not used to scripting in this environment except for some basic so I am sure I am missing something obvious and I try to provide as much info as I can about what I am doing.
Here the script I set (createzip.sh):

```
tar -cv myArchiveName.zip 
tar -rvf myArchiveName.zip *.txt 
tar -rvf myArchiveName.zip *.pdf 
rm *.txt 
rm *.pdf
```

Executing each one via command line that results as I expect without errors, but using *createzip.sh* this error is raised:

> tar: /dev/rmt0: The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

Here the permissions

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 oracle   dba             234 Aug 31 09:31 createzip.sh
```

I split the tar command in multiple calls because the final script would be like :

```
tar -cv myArchiveName.zip && tar -rvf myArchiveName.zip *.txt && tar -rvf myArchiveName.zip *.pdf && rm *.txt && rm *.pdf
```

*** EDIT AFTER ANSWER ***

I was creating the archive on Unix system and "reading" on in Windows system so I don't notice any error in files due to naming the archive with extension *zip*. No specific request about the archive extension so I can use tar without focusing on this matter.
I use multiple instrucions in order to trace/log steps and concatenate them.

I modify the script like this:

```
tar -cvf myArchiveName.tar *.txt && tar -rvf myArchiveName.tar *.pdf && rm *.txt && rm *.pdf
```

Trying to execute **createtar.sh** raise this error:

> createtar.sh:  not found.

The script execute correctly only with **dot command (full stop)**

```
. createtar.sh
```

but is not clear to me which is the meaning/function of it.

Comment: The first problem is that `tar` doesn't create `zip` files.

Comment: @KJ You are right, bsdtar (included in MS Windows as C:\system32\tar.exe) does support many different archive-formats. I didn't know that so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `tar` do not create `zip` file, it create `tar` file
2. in UNIX you need to specify the filename otherwise `tar` use first tape device:
   `tar -cvf myArchiveName.tar *.txt *.pdf`
3. You do not need to explicitly add files (`-r`), combine them as show above
4. The same is true about `rm` command:
   `rm *.txt *.pdf`

You can create it on line like this:

```
tar -cvf myArchiveName.tar *.txt *.pdf && rm *.txt *.pdf
```

Comment: EDITED question after answer

Comment: @AlexMI, I see no reason to split the command. Just create and add in one step.

Comment: I would like to have a sort of hierarchy in command executed so I would like to remove files only if the tar creation sucess, not sure is the best way.

Comment: @AlexMI, check my edited answer (last line)

Comment: you are obviously right and I agree with you (I previously test like you suggest) but I am trying to wrap it in a script in order to pass the archive name as a parameter and, last but not least, I will call the script via Oracle Scheduler

Comment: @AlexMI, with these changes this become new question. Please create and refer this one and do not forget to add all those details.